# Xcode project with a certain Product name crashes at launch

Tags: xcode, macos, appkit, xcode-project

After I finished my Xcode project (macOS app), I wanted to change its name, folder names and other stuff... Everything messed up and the project wouldn't build so I decided to save all the project files in a folder, create a new Xcode project and place the original files there.

So the new project builds completely fine, but it crashes at launch with this message

> container_create_or_lookup_for_current_user(): 8

But the weirdest part is that even if I create an empty project but with the original product name/project name, Xcode won't run the app. Same error.

How can I solve this?
I cleaned the build folder, deleted Derived data, restarted pc.

UPD. When I edit scheme and set debug process as ROOT, app doesn't crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting old app folders in ~/Library/Containers fixed the issue.